# python variable as argument

Tags: python, linux, pexpect

I am using pexpect to run some linux command. I'm having trouble using variable inside of a command. Ex:

```
first_dir="/opt/dirA"
second_dir="/opt/dirB"
```

I want to copy dirA into dirB:

```
cmd="cp -rp " +first_dir +" " +second_dir
print("cmd is ",cmd)
s.sendline(cmd)
```

It's giving an error: missing destination file operand after `/opt/dirA'
But the print output is right (cp -rp /opt/dirA /opt/dirB) and the following command works
    s.sendline("cp -rp /opt/dirA /opt/dirB")

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is `repr(cmd)`? Btw. use string format instead of `+`.

Comment: repr(cmd) gives me 'cp -rp /opt/dirA /opt/dirB\x1b]0;root@myserver:~\x07 /opt/dirB

Comment: If all that stuff is in the `repr`, then you've clearly somehow edited some cursor-movement control codes into your script. The fix is to edit the script in a proper editor that can fix those. You may also want to figure out how you edited it wrong in the first place to make sure you don't do that again. My guess is you did something like `cat > script.py`?

Comment: Meanwhile, is there a reason you're trying to `pexpect` a shell? If you want to use Python, it can do things like copy files (see `shutil`) or run arbitrary programs (see `subprocess`) for you. If you want to script the shell, bash itself is generally better for that than Python…

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to find what I did wrong. I need to use pexpect because I want to automate tasks that takes a couple of hours and where user needs to answer a couple of prompts. I'll edit my queston once I found what's wrong in my code.

Comment: that error is not from python, it's from *nix.

Comment: When posting code, prefer complete, self-contained examples that you verify will show the problem. It takes five minutes longer for you, but it makes the question dramatically much more useful for future readers, and much easier to answer. In your case, you say you've defined two variables which should indeed have worked, but I suspect you instead read the variables from the pexpect session and got some unwanted ANSI escapes sequences along with them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `first_dir` and `second_dir` aren't strings. Try `first_dir = "/opt/dirA"`.

Comment: yes sorry I wrote this too quickly. I made the changes, they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to use os.environ array.
You can find an example here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
first_dir = os.environ["first_dir"]
second_dir = os.environ["second_dir"]
```

As you can see, the script reads the Linux environmental variable first_dir and second_dir into two Python variables of the same name.